# Groovy "truth" check interferes with a GORM detached criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using quite and old stack: Grails 2.5.4, but I can't update. I think I hit a weird bug but I am not sure where and it's really puzzling me...

I have this method in a service:

```
DetachedCriteria crit = myService.getUserCriteria(filter)
```

the returned crit object may be null, meaning that filter must not be applied, or this detached criteria (which is correct, given the domains):

```
new DetachedCriteria(MyDomain).build {
   createAlias('myCollection', 'tp')
   eq('tp.code', filter)
}
```

If I check whether the criteria is null with this statement everything goes fine:

```
if(crit != null) {
   // do work with criteria
}
```

but if I check it like this:

```
if(crit) {
   // do work with criteria
}
```

I get all sorts of weird errors like this one:
"can't get property 'tp' on MyDomain"

I found a workaround, but can someone tell me how the truth check is "breaking" my criteria?

Comment: Is the groovy truth working (second if)?

Comment: usually yes: it returns false for any null o empty (collection, string) value, true otherwise. It's working, since the code gets executed if  crit is null, but it is somehow "breaking" the criteria itself